# Selenium webdriver unable to open a webpage in a capybara based framework

Tags: cucumber, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch a webpage using capybara & selenium webdriver using cucumber. A browser is launched but it's not able to load the url. Below is my `env.rb` file

```
begin require 'rspec/expectations'; 
rescue LoadError; 
require 'spec/expectations'; 
end

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/session'
require 'selenium-webdriver'


Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

    profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1 # manual proxy config
    profile["network.proxy.http"] = "proxybank.icici.net"
    profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 8080

    profile.native_events = true 

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)

  end



app_host = "https://mobilebanking.icici.com"

Capybara.app_host = app_host

Capybara.run_server = true

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

---

The error i get is below

```
D:\cucumberproject>cucumber
In Steps.rb file
Feature: My first feature

  Scenario: launch google page # features\google.feature:4

*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded

*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} installed
in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on jqs@sun.com installed in winreg-app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found


  Given I launch the browser # features/step_definitions/google_steps.rb:5
      Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2211:in `read_status_line'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2200:in `read_new'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1183:in `transport_request'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1169:in `request'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1162:in `block in request'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
      C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1160:in `request'
      ./features/step_definitions/google_steps.rb:9:in `/^I launch the browser$/
'
      features\google.feature:5:in `Given I launch the browser'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features\google.feature:4 # Scenario: launch google page

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
1m14.891s
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
```

Comment: It seems selenium has timed out after waiting for the browser to launch. You should try increasing the webdriver wait time for the browser launch.

Comment: increased the default wait time using "Capybara.default_wait_time = 10", no luck. I think the problem is related to proxy, because i use proxy in my browser, what i have observed is the browser that is launched by webdriver doesn't have proxy setting where my actual browser has proxy settings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** `server_boot_timeout` has been *removed* in Capybara 2.

**For Capybara 2**
You could try putting a `wait.until` and see if it helps. You will need to `require 'selenium-webdriver'` at the top of the file.

Change the following line:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
```

to this:

```
capybara_driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
driver = capybara_driver.browser

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 300)
wait.until { driver.title.downcase.start_with? "my page title" }
```

If this does not work you could also try using plain old ruby sleep.

```
sleep(5.minutes)
```

**For Capybara < 2**
Try increasing the `Capybara.server_boot_timeout` value. Use the following (add the line if it does not exist) in your `env.rb` file.

```
Capybara.server_boot_timeout = 300 # 5 mins
```

Do not mistake this with `Capybara.default_wait_time` which is actually used when running the tests. Also both these properties take values in `seconds`.

Update these values before calling the actual web driver. Probably just after all the `require` statements.

Comment: Added "Capybara.server_boot_timeout = 300" in my env.rb file and then ran my script. It says "undefined method 'server_boot_timeout=' for Capybara:Module <NoMethodError>"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `app_host` = "https://mobilebanking.icici.com"

`Capybara.app_host = app_host`

Then you have to set `Capybara.run_server` to `false`. This is because if `Capybara.run_server` is `true` then it will host the app on default ROR server on your machine and then hit localhost from browser to open the web app.

So, setting `Capybara.run_server = false` in `env.rb` should resolve the issue.

Comment: This works perfectly and is much cleaner than doing the selenium from Tanzeel.